# Aligning sample data

Tags: r, clustering

Given a data matrix like this:

```
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]
 [1,]  9.520 11.137 16.576 18.225 20.576 25.861     NA
 [2,]  9.005  9.491 11.106 16.530 18.184 20.495 25.773
 [3,]  9.437 11.050 20.393 25.711     NA     NA     NA
 [4,]  9.442 11.058 20.411 25.711     NA     NA     NA
 [5,]  9.431 11.045 20.421 25.707     NA     NA     NA
 [6,]  9.461 11.052 20.319 25.657     NA     NA     NA
 [7,]  9.245 10.819 20.253 25.628     NA     NA     NA
 [8,]  9.229 10.801 20.216 25.594     NA     NA     NA
 [9,]  9.234 10.805 20.258 25.619     NA     NA     NA
[10,]  9.241 10.814 20.264 25.626     NA     NA     NA
[11,]  9.248 10.819 20.281 25.649     NA     NA     NA
[12,]  9.231 10.800 20.219 25.567     NA     NA     NA
```

How do I get a data frame like this?:

```
 S     p1     p2     p3     p4     p5     p6     p7
 1     NA  9.520 11.137 16.576 18.225 20.576 25.861     
 2  9.005  9.491 11.106 16.530 18.184 20.495 25.773
 3     NA  9.437 11.050     NA     NA 20.393 25.711
 4     NA  9.442 11.058     NA     NA 20.411 25.711
 5     NA  9.431 11.045     NA     NA 20.421 25.707
 6     NA  9.461 11.052     NA     NA 20.319 25.657
 7     NA  9.245 10.819     NA     NA 20.253 25.628
 8     NA  9.229 10.801     NA     NA 20.216 25.594
 9     NA  9.234 10.805     NA     NA 20.258 25.619
10     NA  9.241 10.814     NA     NA 20.264 25.626 
11     NA  9.248 10.819     NA     NA 20.281 25.649 
12     NA  9.231 10.800     NA     NA 20.219 25.567
```

In the matrix, each row represent the timepoints from 1 sample. The matrix is balanced with an arbitrary number of NAs as needed. In the dataframe, each column represents all the timepoints that are functionally equivalent. Timepoints in a single sample cannot be functionally equivalent.

I think I should be able to solve this with some form of kmeans clustering that restricts each cluster from having more than one member from each sample.  Any ideas?

Comment: I think I get the idea, but I'm concerned my guess could be mistaken.  Could you perhaps elaborate on what you mean by "functionally equivalent"?  That seems to be key to the whole process.  Also, there seem to be some unstated constraints.  Is it the case that each row is always sorted ascending?  Are the samples in a natural sequence (like a time series) or not?  What is the reason for the missingness?  How should an "NA" be interpreted?  I also suspect that explaining how these "timepoints" were measured and what they mean could help people make worthwhile suggestions.

Comment: @whuber: The data is from a set of NMR sample spectra. The spectra are plots of response over time. The timepoints are taken at the centre of each response peak. Ideally, samples with the same compounds will have peaks at the same timepoints. But usually the actual timepoints of identical compounds can vary a little. That's what I mean by "functionally equivalent". The rows are sorted ascending and when the eventual clusters are sorted, the original order of each sample must be maintained. NA is padding in the matrix, but means that there is no peak in that sample at that time in the df.

Comment: So do you have seven actual compounds?  Each row in the original data is a sample, but you don't necessarily get a measurement against all seven; and you don't know which of the seven you missed out on?  If so, the problem is that the NAs are padding it out to the right, when really they might be meant to be in an earlier column?  Interesting problem.

Comment: I thought it looked spectral, but I had guessed something like GC retention times.  NMR spectra are much richer than a bunch of numbers: their interpretation involves relationships among small constellations of peaks.  Thus it's surprising the data have been digested in such a way.  Is there any possibility of re-processing the original output?

Comment: @PeterEllis: In this sample set, there are 7 possible peaks but not every sample has every peak. The data would perhaps be better represented initially as a list of samples with no NAs. But I hate using lists in R.

Comment: @whuber: turns out you're correct, they are GC retention times. (Hey! I'm just the programmer)  I am blushing brightly. I'll add a snippet of original complete data to the question.

Comment: That's ok.  The solution I just finished posting will work even better for GC times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collectively, these data form the spectrum of an idealized *physical* sample containing a  mixture of each of the rows, each with an equal mixture of whichever of the seven analytes it may contain.  **Estimate that spectrum as a (distributional) mixture**.  It's simple: forget the case numbers; flatten all the values in the dataset into a single array; and make a kernel density estimate.

Here is one estimate using a kernel density with halfwidth of 0.25:

[image: Spectrum]

**Use the modes of this combined spectrum to identify the peaks present in the mixture.**  (A mode identifies the central time in a set of "functionally equivalent" values.)  **Assign each number in the dataset to the nearest peak**.  (You could be a little fancier by also estimating the peak half-widths from the full spectrum and using these to weight the distances, but that's probably unnecessary.  You can also provide a "confidence" value, perhaps by giving the ratio between the distance to the nearest peak and the distance to the second-nearest peak; values near 0 would be strong and values close to 1 would be weak.  More sophisticated measures based on probability assumptions and likelihoods are possible as well.)

The output would be in the form

```
Case Peak   Time
   1    1  9.520
   1    2 11.137
   1    3 16.576
   1    4 18.225
   1    5 20.576
   1    6 25.861
   2    1  9.005
   2    1  9.491
 ...
  12    1  9.231
  12    2 10.800
  12    5 20.219
  12    6 25.567
```

This is readily transformed to any format you like.

Notice how this dataset is insufficient to separate the peak near 9.0 (having low amplitude: it appears in only one case) from that near 9.5; that's why the kernel density estimate identifies only 6 peaks, not 7, and assigns two values from case 2 to the same peak.

If you don't need to estimate the peak locations from the combined spectrum (they might already be known), then you can skip the kernel density estimation altogether and simply assign each value to the nearest known peak.  That's one way to resolve the difficulty in your sample data around the 9-9.5 pair of peaks.

**There are some choices to be made**, which are best guided by your knowledge of these spectra.  The choices concern the kernel density bandwidths: they should not exceed the actual half-widths of the spectral peaks.  They also concern how many modes to identify. (This is often done by a "library search" to match peaks and sets of peaks to calibrated results for pure substances, but when you are looking for a small well-separated set of high individual peaks, you don't need that kind of sophistication and almost any crude mode-identifying procedure will do.)

Comment: Thanks for an excellent explanation! I've got what appears to a reasonable kernel density estimation with R using either `density(myd,bw='sj',adjust=0.25))` or `kde(x=myd,h=bw.SJ(myd))` which I arrived at by fiddling until the density plot looked right. But I'm stymied at how to extract the modes from this. Any suggestions or should that be a separate post?

Comment: Do you need to automate the mode finding?  If not, drawing a plot and reading off the modes might do the trick for your data.

Comment: Excellent suggestion and I like the simplicity of collapsing the data.  Assigning each value to the nearest known peak is what I was trying to do in my answer (which I have now deleted) but I complicated it greatly and unnecessarily by keeping to a row by row method.

Comment: @whuber: I do need to automate the mode finding. Right now the researchers are doing it all by eye and it takes forever with the volume we have.  If I can reduce that burden to scanning for anomalies, they'll be able to get more done.

Comment: General-purpose mode finding like that (with an unknown number of modes of unknown heights) is sufficiently complicated that it's worth a new question.  The topic straddles the interests of this site and the StackOverflow site, which has a strong R community, so you could post that follow-up either place.  Given that the modes arise as peaks of a KDE, which is a statistical procedure, I think your follow-up would be on-topic here, provided you made it clear that your problem truly is a statistical one (and not purely numerical).

Answer (score -1):

Actually I still not sure what is the reason to do that.

My solutions:

1. Retype your dataframe :-P
2. Ok, #1 is not working, so I just did [some codes](http://cloudst.at/index.php?do=/kaichew/blog/aligning-sample-data/) specific for only this case.

[image: 1/3]
[image: 2/3]
[image: 3/3]

Hope it help :)

Comment: This will only work if it is always p1, p4 and p5 that should have the NAs.  Is this the case?  If so the problem's a bit simpler than my own answer makes out.

Comment: @Peter Ellis: I still not sure what dnagirl wanted, so I just wrote according the current situation. If she needed not only p1, p4... that's another case, then we can rewrite the commands :-)